# Pandas - loop through dataframe, check column values if empty, if empty then add entire row to new list or df

Tags: pandas

Currently my database looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

output =  [['Owner', 'Database', 'Schema', 'Table', 'Column', 'Comment', 'Status'], ['', 'VICE_DEV', 'AIRFLOW', 'TASK_INSTANCE', '_LOAD_DATETIME', 'Load datetime'], ['', 'VICE_DEV', 'AIRFLOW', 'TEST', '_LOAD_FILENAME', 'load file name', 'ADDED']]

df = pd.DataFrame(output[1:], columns=output[0])
```

It looks like this:

```
  Owner  Database   Schema  ...          Column         Comment Status
0        VICE_DEV  AIRFLOW  ...  _LOAD_DATETIME   Load datetime   None
1        VICE_DEV  AIRFLOW  ...  _LOAD_FILENAME  load file name  ADDED
```

I'm now trying to loop through the Status col, and if Status is None or empty I want to create a list of SQL string queries, and go to the next row and check, etc.

I've tried this:

```
query_list = []

for column in df['Status']:
    if column is None:
        sql = f"ALTER TABLE {df['Table']} ALTER {df['Column']} COMMENT {df['Comment']}; "
        # print(sql)
        query_list.append(sql)
```

But its not correct, its getting both rows, instead I want to only get the rows with the column df['Status'] None (or empty). Also, the formatting is off. I've tried by creating an empty list and an empty df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to create one query if `Status` is `None`. This query uses the values from the particular row that is `None`. The problem then is that you insert whole columns into your query and not the values from the particular row with `Status==None`. I think what you want is to iterate over all columns in your dataframe and then check if the status is `None`. If so, create the query based on that row. This can be done with the following code for example:

```
import pandas as pd

output =  [['Owner', 'Database', 'Schema', 'Table', 'Column', 'Comment', 'Status'], ['', 'VICE_DEV', 'AIRFLOW', 'TASK_INSTANCE', '_LOAD_DATETIME', 'Load datetime'], ['', 'VICE_DEV', 'AIRFLOW', 'TEST', '_LOAD_FILENAME', 'load file name', 'ADDED']]

df = pd.DataFrame(output[1:], columns=output[0])

query_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Status'] is None:
        sql = f"ALTER TABLE {row['Table']} ALTER {row['Column']} COMMENT {row['Comment']}; "
        
        # print(sql)
        query_list.append(sql)
query_list
```

Output:

```
['ALTER TABLE TASK_INSTANCE ALTER _LOAD_DATETIME COMMENT Load datetime; ']
```

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!